# JS: How to pass url through redirect function to login function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redirect, next.js

In my React/nextJS application I'm checking for a valid token in the `getInitialProps` static function.
I'm using this as a HOC - but this should not matter in this case.

If the the token is invalid (or missing) the user gets redirected to the login page. This is done by the `redirect` function as shown below. So far, so good.

How can I pass the url of the page from which the user gets redirected to the login component?

If the user is not logged in and is calling something like *http://my-server.com/any-page*, he gets redirected to the index page (*http://my-server.com*): There will be a login form. If the login is successful, I would like to redirect him back to the first called page: *http://my-server.com/any-page*

1. Call a restricted page as not logged in user
2. Redirect to index login page
3. After login redirect back to the page of 1.

I don't have a clue how to pass this information to the login function...

**with-server-props.js**

```
export default WrappedComponent =>
  class extends Component {
    static async getInitialProps (context) {
      const { req, pathname } = context
      let isValid = false

      if (req && req.headers) {
        const cookies = req.headers.cookie
        if (typeof cookies === 'string') {
          const cookiesJSON = jsHttpCookie.parse(cookies)
          initProps.token = cookiesJSON['auth-token']
          if (cookiesJSON['auth-token']) {
            jwt.verify(cookiesJSON['auth-token'], secret, (error, decoded) => {
              if (error) {
                console.error(error)
              } else {
                isValid = true
              }
            })
          }
        }
      }

      // Redirect to index (=login) page if isValid is false
      if (!isValid && pathname && pathname !== '/') {
        redirect(context, pathname ? '/?ref=' + pathname : '/')
      }

      return initProps
    }
    render () {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }
```

**redirect.js**

```
import Router from 'next/router'

export default (context, target) => {
  if (context.res) {
    // server
    context.res.writeHead(303, { Location: target })
    context.res.end()
  } else {
    // In the browser, we just pretend like this never even happened ;)
    Router.replace(target)
  }
}
```

**pages/index.js**

On index.js there is the `submit` function to login the user. There the user should be redirected to the initial page:

```
_onSubmit (event) {
  this.props.loginMutation({
    variables: { username, password }
  }).then(response => {
    const token = response.data.token
    if (token) {
      Cookies.set('auth-token', token, { expires: 1 })
      this.props.client.resetStore().then(() => {
        window.location.assign('/') // <-- Redirect to initial called page
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: maybe just store initial url into local/session storage, and check it after log in?

Comment: In react most elegant way to pass data is by props. But 'next/router' is doing routing so there is no way you can pass data by props. And since you are replacing instead of pushing so it won't saved in 'history' either. And other than props there is multiple way to pass data for example 'global variable', 'local storage', 'redux etc third party store'. I think using 'redux' or other store is better way of sharing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `with-server-props.js` replace the path with an [URL object](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#with-url-object-1)

```
redirect(context, {
    pathname: '/',
    query: { redirect: req.url } // req.url should give you the current url on server side
  })
```

this will add a redirect param to the url *https://example.com/?redirect=/about*

then you can get the url params on any page using the `getInitialProps`:

```
this.redirectUrl = (req && req.query['redirect']) ? decodeURIComponent(req.query['redirect']) : '/'
```

finally

```
window.location.assign(this.redirectUrl)
```

hope it helps, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `react-router` or more specifically the `react-router-dom` package. It's a breeze if you understand the way it works.

For your scenario, instead of calling `redirect()` when not authenticated, you use `<Redirect to={url} />`. This automatically does a browser url replace and updates global state.You'd have already subtly assigned a url that matches any special case to trap though. E.g. "/login/ref/:toref" will be the base expression to handle url "/login/ref/{specialaccess}".

*Note the ":". It is the params matcher and is needed to retrieve the url in the login component.*

As they say, a line of code is worth a thousand words. So I made a little project to demonstrate fully how one could implement some of the important features of `react-router-dom`.

Find here: https://codesandbox.io/s/y0znxpk30z

In the project when you try to access https://y0znxpk30z.codesandbox.io/specialaccess through the browser simulator, you get redirected to the special access page after becoming authenticated on login. Otherwise if you access https://y0znxpk30z.codesandbox.io then you get redirected to the home page after login.

Remember, you have to wrap any component that expects global props `withRouter` like this:

```
export default withRouter(component-name);
```

This provides `this.props.location`, `this.props.history` and `this.props.match` in every component because we already placed the app's root component inside the `<BrowserRouter><BrowserRouter/>` HOC available by default from the package.

With `this.props.match` we can easily refer to and redirect back to the url we specified in ":toref" previously.

You can read more about `react-router` [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/match)

Comment: That sounds great. I'm not quite sure, but nextJS also has a routing module. If this is the case, isn't it possible to use that one in a similar way?

Comment: Maybe something like https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#using-a-higher-order-component ?

Comment: Yes, nextJS has it's routing module but it does not handle as much complicated routing as `react-router`. As you can read from here https://react-etc.net/entry/next-js-to-adopt-react-router `react-router` will still be adopted to nextJS. So, if you're doing dynamic routing on front-end, `react-router` is still your best bet, at least to my knowledge thus far.

Answer (score 0):

`jwt.verify` function is used in an async callback manner.

That style is more fitting for the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method of the `WrappedComponent` used that way.
Passing a callback for it means that the value for `isValid` may never be updated early enough even when the client JWT token is a valid one and the user will always be redirected.

I suggest to use the synchronous variant without a callback (test to compare how much time before the wrapped component is rendered). Even better, convert `jwt.verify` callback style to a function that returns a promise so that it can be resolved in an `await` expression given that `getInitialProps` is an `async` function.

```
if (req && req.headers) {
  const cookies = req.headers.cookie
  if (typeof cookies === 'string') {
    const cookiesJSON = jsHttpCookie.parse(cookies)
    initProps.token = cookiesJSON['auth-token']
    if (cookiesJSON['auth-token']) {
      try {
         const payload = jwt.verify(cookiesJSON['auth-token'], secret)
         if (payload) {
            isValid = true
         }
      } catch (err) {
         isValid = false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now in the `_onsubmit` method to redirect the user, you can get the `ref` query parameter value set in `WrappedComponent.getInitialProps` and use that to redirect the user.

```
const ref = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('ref');
location.assign(`/${ref}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the return url either as a query parameter or as location state to the login page. I found an example on the documentation page for Next.js on pushing a route with query parameters.

```
import Router from 'next/router'

const handler = () => {
  Router.push({
    pathname: '/about',
    query: { name: 'Zeit' }
  })
}

export default () => (
  <div>
    Click <span onClick={handler}>here</span> to read more
  </div>
)
```

Instead of a Router.replace, try Router.push with the return url passed in from the HOC. Hope this helps.